# Typescript - A function which returns a function with generic type - what does it do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

I am new to TypeScript and came across a piece of code which confused me to no end. I am trying to understand what the function `componentControl` does below but I don't think I fully grasp it.

`componentControl:`

```
const componentControl: <P extends object>(
  options: BaseProps<P>
) => React.FunctionComponent<P> = <P extends object>(options: BaseProps<P>) => {
  const defaultBaseProps = {
    onInit: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onLoading: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onLoaded: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onSubmit: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onSubmitSuccess: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onDestroy: undefined,
    onError: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onLoadingFailure: () => Promise.resolve(),
    onSubmitFailure: () => Promise.resolve(),
    InitComponent: () => <PageSpinner />,
    LoadingComponent: () => <PageSpinner />,
    LoadedComponent: () => <h1>The component has been loaded.</h1>,
    SubmittingComponent: () => <PageSpinner />,
    SubmitSuccessComponent: () => <h1>Submitted successfully.</h1>,
    ErrorComponent: DefaultErrorComponent,
    LoadingFailureComponent: DefaultErrorComponent,
    SubmitFailureComponent: DefaultErrorComponent,
  };
  return (wrapped: P) => {
    const props: BaseComponentProps<P> = {
      base: { ...defaultBaseProps, ...options },
      wrapped: wrapped
    };
    return <BaseComponent {...props} />;
  };
};
```

`BaseProps:`

```
export interface BaseProps<P> {
  onInit?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;
  onLoading?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;
  onLoaded?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;
  onSubmit?: (
    props: P & BaseContextType & { submittedData: unknown }
  ) => Promise<void>;
  onSubmitSuccess?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;
  onDestroy?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;
  onError?: (
    props: { err: Error | string | unknown } & BaseContextType
  ) => Promise<void>;
  onLoadingFailure?: (
    props: { err: Error | string | unknown } & BaseContextType
  ) => Promise<void>;
  onSubmitFailure?: (
    props: { err: Error | string | unknown } & BaseContextType
  ) => Promise<void>;

  InitComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<P>;
  LoadingComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<P>;
  LoadedComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<P>;
  SubmittingComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<P>;
  SubmitSuccessComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<P>;
  ErrorComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<
    P & { err: Error | string | unknown }
  >;
  LoadingFailureComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<
    P & { err: Error | string | unknown }
  >;
  SubmitFailureComponent?: React.FunctionComponent<
    P & { err: Error | string | unknown }
  >;
}
```

`BaseComponentProps:`

```
export interface BaseComponentProps<P> {
  base: BaseProps<P>;
  wrapped: P;
}
```

If I hover over the function name `componentControl` in IntelliJ, it shows this: `export default function componentControl<P>(options: BaseProps<P>): (wrapped: P) => JSX.Element`. What exactly is the input of the this function? Is it the `options` of type `BaseProps` or `wrapped` of type `P`? What is the use of `wrapped`? And does this function returns this function below?

```
(wrapped: P) => {
    const props: BaseComponentProps<P> = {
      base: { ...defaultBaseProps, ...options },
      wrapped: wrapped
    };
    return <BaseComponent {...props} />;
  };
```

Finally, how am I supposed to use/call this function? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: What does `BaseComponent` look like? Because that's where all these props actually get used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's go step by step:

1. **What exactly is the input of this function?**: The input/arguments of this function (`componentControl`) it's an `options` object (which should follow the constraints specified in the `BaseProps` interface. Bear in mind you will also need to send the value for the generic type `P` in my example is the `{someProp: boolean}` interface. This will tell your component that the value of `P` is that interface so if u try to send as props an `onInit` function that does not have `{someProp: boolean}` as the argument type it will return an error. This constrain is defined in the `BaseProps` interface here `onInit?: (props: P & BaseContextType) => Promise<void>;` where `P` === `{someProp: boolean}` in my example.
2. **Is it the options of type BaseProps or wrapped of type P?** : As I said the argument of that function is the `options` object.
3. **What is the use of wrapped?** : The function `componentControl` returns a functional component (as you can see its typed in line 3 `) => React.FunctionComponent<P>`. So if you do:

```js
const NewControledComponent = componentControl<{someProp: boolean}>({onInit}) // P === {someProp}

<NewControledComponent someProp={false} /> // wrapped === props === {someProp: false}
```

`wrapped` is only the name used to reference the component props (calling them `props` or `wrappedComponentProps` would be more accurate.

3. **And does this function returns this function below?**: Yes, it return the function below which it means to be a `React Functional Component`
4. **how am I supposed to use/call this function?**: Like a normal function, but you need to bear in mind that it will return a React functional Component.